# ASP.NET domain authentication working local workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC Application that uses Windows authentication.

```
 <authentication mode="Windows">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="DomainName\Domain Users" />
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

The current configuration requires to work on a PC within the domain "DomainName" to be able to debug the Application. There is some special user management running behind the scenes.
I'm not able to work on a PC within the domain - instead I'd like to work locally on my PC with a local user account. I also have a domain account on this domain to access specific resources.

Now my question is: Is there any way to imitate a domain account to work with the Debugger in IISExpress on my machine with a local user account?

I already tried "runas" but was not successful.

Comment: I suggest building a VM you can join to the domain in question for debugging these features.

Comment: If you have access to the application in IIS you can allow impersonation. I normally impersonate a service account and store the details as a key in my registry.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm using IISExpress to debug locally. I should set impersonation there.

Comment: You would first have to impersonate an account that is already set up and active on the server-side Active Directory. Honestly, the easiest/fastest route would be to go ahead and get permission from your company to join the Domain on a VM and do your work from there like Joel said. Either way, you're going to have to contact the server admin.